# Is there a clean magento installation without any module present in package?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I'm just wandering is there some magento package that can be downloaded, without admin and all ecommerce modules, just a clean framework ready to develop my own modules from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-lite).  Probably the closest thing to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Magento Lite, that's what you are looking for;

https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-lite

And this is the lite version of Magento so far we get freely :) for general purpose.

Otherwise you will have to disable more modules from it based on your need